# ModelBuilder - Convert Empty line feature class to a point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, feature-class

I have a ModelBuilder to work as a tool.
The workflow is that buffer 30 meters in the rivers and then intersect with classification feature class (vegetation and production area) then the result is selected (only the production area) and is converted to "feature to line" and then "feature to point" but when the feature class resulted from intersection is empty I find a error and the tool does't run completly. 
My wish is to run the tool to delivery even a empty feature class (point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check to determine if the feature class is empty; if it isn't empty, run your conversions (I'd just go for centroids rather than going from poly to line to point), and if it is empty, skip it or add a message/log file.

Comment: [`GetCount()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/get-count.htm)--the link actually shows how to use it in MB--though you'll need to create a 2nd branch that creates an empty feature class.